# Resources on implementing a design into Android

Tags: designers, resource-recommendations, android

I'm an Android developer and I'm new into graphic design. Since my first day I felt that graphic design would become a problem.

I already worked with styles.xml, color.xml, etc. to change application style, and I made various simple drawables out of shapes like rects to make simple variation to the standard looking widgets.

The last thing I tried to do is to make a vector shape, a trapezoid, to insert it as background drawable to a TextView, but I found it darn impossible to make that shape.

Can you link me some tutorials for beginners (that are **not** something like how-to-change-text-color-in-xml level) or guides or even books if you know some?

Comment: Hey jj. Please stick to one question per post and read through our requirements for questions in the help section. Your questions are too broad for this Q&A format.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.Can you please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/130447/edit) and show exactly what you mean by "make it good" and "fit beautifully", and what you have tried/what has failed. Unfortunately as this stands, this question is far to broad.

Comment: ok i'll do an editing

Comment: done! i explicited what i've worked with

Comment: I edited your question to focus more on the resource recommendations, since it was quite broad to answer. Feel free to edit or rollback if you think it detracts too much from what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector image editor to create the required shape, and save as SVG.  Inkscape is free, so try that.

1. Draw a rectangle using the Rectangle tool <kbd>F4</kbd>
2. Click *Path > Object to path* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Use the Select by Nodes tool <kbd>F2</kbd> to move the corner nodes as required. After clicking on a node, holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Ctrl as you drag will constrain the move horizontally/vertically.
4. Set the object fill and stroke colour as required in the Fill and Stroke panel <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
5. Click *File > Save as* - and choose "Plain SVG" as the file type.

Then you could [convert it to Android Drawable XML](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-svg-vector-drawables-in-android) using Android Studio's Vector Asset functionality.